# Usage of this sometimes necessary?

Tags: c++, templates

just stumbled upon something i can't explain. The following code doesn't compile

```
template<int a>
class sub{
protected:
    int _attr;
};

template<int b>
class super : public sub<b>{
public:
    void foo(){
        _attr = 3;
    }
};

int main(){
    super<4> obj;
    obj.foo();
}
```

whereas when i change `_attr = 3;` to `this->attr = 3;` there seems to be no problem.

Why is that? Are there any cases you must to use this?

I used `g++ test.cpp -Wall -pedantic` to compile and i get the following error

```
test.cpp: in member function 'void super<b>::foo()':
test.cpp:11:3: error: '_attr' was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: Read up on [two-phase name lookup](http://blog.llvm.org/2009/12/dreaded-two-phase-name-lookup.html). (Also this FAQ: [Why am I getting errors when my template-derived-class uses a member it inherits from its template-base-class?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/nondependent-name-lookup-members.html))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Why is that? Are there any cases you must to use this?`

Yes, there are some cases where you need to use `this`. In your example, when the compiler sees `_attr`, it tries to look for `_attr` inside the class and cannot find it. By adding `this->` you *delay* lookup until instantiation time which allows the compiler to find it inside of `sub`.

Another very common reason to use this is to resolve ambiguity problems:

```
void foo (int i)
{
   this->i = i;
}
```